# How can I archive Resharper run log of NUnit tests

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

My question is very trivial, yet I didn't found the answer myself:

Where does Resharper store the results from last Nunit tests run? there must be a file somewhere. Is it human-readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is export button on toolbar of almost each tree view.
You can export results in Text, XML or HTML format.